# SWIFT 2 Global variable doesn't contain any data. Inside the scope there were data.

Tags: swift

> Global variable doesn't contain any data.  Inside the scope there were data. NSLog tells me that my data inside the function GetJsonDataFromURL contains data in it.

'Please do explain to me why and what is the industry standard way of handling the variables and data been debugging this for a few days now'

```
var employeeData : Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [:]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GetJsonDataFromURL()
    NSLog("%@", employeeData) <- THIS LINE HAS NO DATA
}

func GetJsonDataFromURL() {

    let postEndpoint: String = "http://localhost/watsdis/showOutbox.php"
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint)!
    var dataContainer : Dictionary <String, String> = [:]
    var mobiles : Dictionary <String, String> = [:]
    var msgs : Dictionary <String, String> = [:]
    var ids : [String] = []
    var names : Dictionary <String, String> = [:]
    var pos = ""
    // Make the POST call and handle it in a completion handler
    session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, let error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // Make sure we get an OK response
        guard let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where
                  realResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            print("Not a 200 response")
                    return
        }

        // Read the JSON
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
            if let employees = json["employee"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for employee in employees {
                    if let id = employee["id"] as? String {
                        ids.append (id)
                        pos = id
                    }
                    if let mobile = employee["mobile"] as? String {
                        mobiles[pos] = mobile
                    }
                    if let msg = employee["msg"] as? String {
                        msgs[pos] = msg
                    }
                    if let name = employee["name"] as? String {
                        names[pos] = name
                    }

                }
            }
            self.employeeData["id"] = ids
            self.employeeData["name"] = names
            self.employeeData["mobile"] = mobiles
            self.employeeData["msg"] = msgs
       } catch {
            print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
        }
        NSLog("%@", self.employeeData) <- THIS LINE DISPLAYS MY DATA IN ARRAY FORMAT
    }).resume();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetJsonDataFromURL` is acsync function 
in `viewDidLoad` you call:

```
GetJsonDataFromURL()
NSLog("%@", employeeData) <- THIS LINE HAS NO DATA
```

NSLog is run before function GetJsonDataFromURL returns data, so it empty data. 
You try:

```
func GetJsonDataFromURL(handleComplete:(isOK:Bool)->()) {

    let postEndpoint: String = "http://localhost/watsdis/showOutbox.php"
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint)!
    var dataContainer : Dictionary <String, String> = [:]
    var mobiles : Dictionary <String, String> = [:]
    var msgs : Dictionary <String, String> = [:]
    var ids : [String] = []
    var names : Dictionary <String, String> = [:]
    var pos = ""
    // Make the POST call and handle it in a completion handler
    session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, let error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // Make sure we get an OK response
        guard let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where
            realResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                print("Not a 200 response")
                return
        }

        // Read the JSON
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
            if let employees = json["employee"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for employee in employees {
                    if let id = employee["id"] as? String {
                        ids.append (id)
                        pos = id
                    }
                    if let mobile = employee["mobile"] as? String {
                        mobiles[pos] = mobile
                    }
                    if let msg = employee["msg"] as? String {
                        msgs[pos] = msg
                    }
                    if let name = employee["name"] as? String {
                        names[pos] = name
                    }

                }
            }
            self.employeeData["id"] = ids
            self.employeeData["name"] = names
            self.employeeData["mobile"] = mobiles
            self.employeeData["msg"] = msgs
            handleComplete(isOK: true)
        } catch {
            handleComplete(isOK: false)
            print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
        }
        NSLog("%@", self.employeeData) <- THIS LINE DISPLAYS MY DATA IN ARRAY FORMAT
    }).resume();
}
```

and in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.GetJsonDataFromURL { (isOK) -> () in
        if isOK{
            print(self.employeeData)
        }else{
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an asynchronous method with a callback. There's a good chance you are checking the variable before the callback that puts data into employeeData gets executed.